# Python: How to return a dictionary where each key is a food and each value is the qty of food that was ordered?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_quantities(table_to_foods):
    """ (dict of {str: list of str}) -> dict of {str: int}

    The table_to_foods dict has table names as keys (e.g., 't1', 't2',
    and so on) and each value is a list of foods ordered for that table.

    Return a dictionary where each key is a food from table_to_foods and   
    each value is the quantity of that food that was ordered.

    >>> get_quantities({'t1': ['Vegetarian stew', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 't3': ['Steak pie', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 't4': ['Steak pie', 'Steak pie']})
    {'Vegetarian stew': 3, 'Poutine': 2, 'Steak pie': 3}    
    """

    food_to_quantity = {}

    # Accumulate the food information here.

    return food_to_quantity
```

I CANNOT IMPORT ANYTHING (collections/chain). I have two options I tried below, but both failed.

This makes the program time out:

```
for table in table_to_foods:
    count = 0
    while count < len(table):
        for food in table[count]:
            if food in food_to_quantity:
                food_to_quantity[food] += 1
            else:
                food_to_quantity[food] = 1
    count += 1
```

This gets an AttributeError:

```
for table_order in table_to_foods.itervalues():
    for menu_item in table_order:
        if menu_item in food_to_quantity:
            food_to_quantity[menu_item] += 1
        else:
            food_to_quantity[menu_item] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. Your second snippet:

```
for table_order in table_to_foods.itervalues():
    for menu_item in table_order:
        if menu_item in food_to_quantity:
            food_to_quantity[menu_item] += 1
        else:
            food_to_quantity[menu_item] = 1
```

is using the old Python 2 `itervalues` method, but you're on Python 3. You should use `values`, which is equivalent to the Python 2.7 `viewvalues` method. With that changed, this snippet should work.

Your first snippet has more problems. For example, `len(table)` is the number of characters in the table name, not anything you're interested in, and you've attempted to use 3 loops with unclear roles. You also placed `count += 1` outside of the loop that uses `count`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly once I changed itervalues to values :) I appreciate that you took the time to explain things to me and I upvoted you even though it doesn't show because I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
def get_quantities(table_to_foods):
    '''
    Takes a dictionary containing a list of strings and returns the
    string and count

    get_quantities(dict(str:[str])) -> dict(str:int)
    '''

    result = {}

    for table in table_to_foods:
        for item in table_to_foods[table]:
            result[item] = result.get(item, 0) + 1
    return result
```

Comment: You don't need `item_list`, you can replace `if item in item_list:` with `if item in result:`. This is the best you can do if you aren't permitted to use dictionary methods beyond these. The inner loop body can be written in one line using the `get` method: `result[item] = result.get(item, 0) + 1`

Comment: This didn't work with the coding system (unfortunately) but I like it way more than what I had. I don't have enough reputation to "officially" upvote you, but I've done so anyways because I really appreciate the time you took to look at this and offer advice / feedback